# How do I add a bounty?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I have over 75 reputation points, but I can't for the life of me see how to add a bounty to my questions. I sometimes have seen "add a bounty" buttons on other people's questions, but not on mine.

The FAQ says nothing about how to add a bounty, so I am presuming I am thick.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the "start a bounty" link under the question. [See this blog entry](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/reputation-bounty-for-unanswered-questions/) for an illustrated guide.

Note that there is a limitation on bounties: you can only start them on questions that are older than two days and don't have an accepted answer yet (this may explain why you don't see the "start a bounty" link on some questions).

Comment: OK, the blog post sorted it:  The question needs to be over 2 days old.  Otherwise, I don't see the darn "start a bounty" link.  You get the accepted answer, but I will add an answer below to show the precise solution in my case

Answer (score 4):

To see the "start a bounty" link, the post needs to be:

1. At least 2 days old
2. Have no accepted answers - EDIT:  this is no longer valid!!! See comment below
3. You can have only one question with a bounty
4. You cannot assign a bounty to a question that already has one.

After that, you get to see the link and so you can add a bounty.

See the link to a blog entry in Piskvor's answer to this thread.

Comment: This data is actually incorrect; the information in the [privilege page](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties), under "Which questions are eligible?", is more accurate. Bounties are no longer tied to accepted answers so you are able to put it on a question with an accepted answer. However, you cannot post it on a question that already has a bounty, or when you already have a current bounty on another question.